# Oracle check constraint with subquerys [exercise]

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to solve this exercise (should be solvable).
You have the following table. The table includes seat reservation, all seats between a start-/enddate are reserved.

```
CREATE TABLE reservation ( 
    owner CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    start INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    end   INTEGER  NOT NULL
)
```

Extend this table definition with an **constraint** what checks, that no place will be reserved twice.

As far as I know it isn't possible to use a subquery in a check constraint. So what kind of constraint can I use?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot do this using constraint.   You need a trigger.stackoverflow.com/questions/8770552/can-i-have-a-constraint-on-count-of-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-sql

Comment: Yes thats what I know so far, but I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Can you alter the table (add more columns, etc)? If yes, then yes, it's possible. Complicated but possible, through DRI alone (FOREIGN KEY, UNIQUE and CHECK constraints).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I am interested to know your approach. Could you please point us to a link, or share your answer below?

Comment: I hope to find an solution without alter the table.

Comment: @I_am_Batman answer added

Comment: In my opinion a before insert trigger is the way to go. Therein simply scan the table for an overlapping range and if you find one raise an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done with a single `CHECK` constraint because essentially it is a constraint that relies on more than one rows of the table.

It's similar to a `UNIQUE` constraint in a way. In a unique constraint, no two rows can have the same values. In this, no two rows can have overlapping ranges. So, if we could replace equality condition (`=`) with a condition that check for overlapping ranges, it would be just right.

In another DBMS (Postgres), it is actually possible to enforce exactly this and similar constraints using the proprietary `EXCLUDE` constraint.

---

In Oracle now and other DBMS that have the common `FOREIGN KEY`, `UNIQUE` and `CHECK` constraints, it is actually possible but complicated, if you are allowed to change the table design by adding another column:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation ( 
    owner CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    start INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    end   INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    previous_end INTEGER NULL,

    CONSTRAINT valid_range
        CHECK (start <= end),
    CONSTRAINT unique_end
        UNIQUE (end), 
    CONSTRAINT previous_range_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (previous_end) 
        REFERENCES reservation (end), 
    CONSTRAINT valid_previous
        CHECK (previous_end < start)
) ;
```

and we are good to go. You just have to provide the `previous_end` value correctly, essentially making the table a linked list. All the constraints work together to ensure that ranges do not overlap.

Comment: Actually I think it also need a `UNIQUE (previous_end)` constraint as well. I'l ledit and correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a materialized view:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation ( 
    owner   CHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "start" INTEGER  NOT NULL,
    "end"   INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON reservation
   WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID("start","end")
   INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW reservation_MV
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
   AS SELECT "start" + LEVEL - 1 AS table_number
      FROM   reservation
      CONNECT BY "start" + LEVEL - 1 <= "end";

ALTER TABLE reservation_MV ADD CONSTRAINT reservation__mv__pk
  PRIMARY KEY ( table_number );
```